# How do I integrate part of one git repository as part of another repository?

Tags: git, github

My situation:

I am working with two Github repositories: A and B, which share a common ancestor, but that have both diverged extensively over several years. I am a collaborator on B, but not on A.

I want to do the following:

1. Merge in changes on a subset of files in multiple folders from repository A to repository B, and do this periodically.
2. Submit changes from repository B (as pull requests) to repository A, that are made on this same subset of files, but without including any history on other files

Let's say that the repositories have the following file structure:

**Repo A:**

```
classes/
    ArchiveManager.php
    ChecklistAdmin.php
    ExploreManager.php
collections/
    editor.php
    reports.php
template/
    header.php
    footer.php
index.php
```

**Repo B:**

```
classes/
    AgentManager.php
    ChecklistAdmin.php
    ExploreManager.php
collections/
    editor.php
    reports.php
template/
    header.php
    footer.php
index.php
```

I want to merge collections/*, classes/ArchiveManager.php, and classes/ChecklistAdmin.php from A > B, so that I have the versions in repo A for those, while gaining any new files in repo A, and keeping any new files in repo B. That's the idea, though the actual project is many more files.

**Clunky ways without git:**

1. Make a script to copy over specific files from a folder with repo A to one with repo B. But this loses all of the commit history from repo A.
2. Take any changes to repo B, copy the files over, merge, and submit a pull request to repo A. But this loses the commit history in B as well, and would be a bit more work.

**Git methods**

1. Submodules and subtrees won't work because I'm trying to sync multiple paths
2. I've tried using sparse-checkout on a local repository where I have each remote repository mapped to a different branch, but merges done from one branch to the other include files that are not part of the sparse-checkout.

Anyone have any ideas?

***Edit:***

I have made some progress, so posting this in case it is helpful to anyone. Or, if someone has a better solution, I'm interested.

1. Clone repository B
2. Add repository A as a remote: `git remote add repoA <path-to-A>`
3. Set up a new branch to track A: `git checkout --track -b branchA repoA/master`
4. Create a new branch to do merging in: `git checkout -b sandbox`
5. Merge branchA into merging, without committing or fast-forwarding: `git merge branchA --no-commit --no-ff`.
6. Create a file avoid-merge.txt with a list of files/folders/wildcard matches in repoB that I want untouched
7. Add avoid-merge.txt and .gitignore to .gitignore
8. Run the following, which will remove the files matched by avoid-merge from the staging area for merging: `cat avoid-merge.txt | while read line; do git reset "$line"; done; git clean -fd`
9. ----- Edit any merge conflicts -----
10. Commit the merge. The sandbox branch can be merged in turn to repoB/master or whatever other branch.

Steps 5-10 can be done on branchA as well (potentially with a different avoid-merge.txt), to send any changes from repoB to repoA.

In both cases, the relevant commits for the files that are merged are kept. At least, this seems to be true so far.

Comment: Git is about *commits*, not files or directories. Repositories are collections of commits, and each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file (even with sparse-checkout: this merely limits which files go into your *working tree*, but the commits still hold every file). Commit history consists of the commits themselves. Either you put *all* the commits—and hence all the files—in the other repository, *or* you have different histories. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @torek: I am aware of this. Git is generally all-or-nothing. However, there are some exceptions, and I'm looking for creative hacked-together solutions that might accomplish this. Both subtrees and sparse-checkout come close, but in different ways.